# Bootstrap grid not working inside HTML5 details element (Chrome)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

It's working fine in Firefox and even an old version of Opera.

**[Failing in Chrome 56  (*Codepen*)](https://codepen.io/caseydwayne/pen/pPWXdJ)**

```
<details>
  <summary>Stuff</summary>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
         ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to work when you add [**`box-sizing: border-box`**](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) to `.row`.

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbMoVZ)